# Load instagram images from user's feed via API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to display only the images the client uploaded to instagram on their website. The client's user ID# is 176722013. According to the API this URL will provide just such a feed:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/176722013/media/recent

As indicated by the error message, I need to provide either a client_id or an auth_token. Since I don't want to deal with authentication I went ahead and created an "app" in instagram developers to get a client_id # 5b5a6e95469f465f9f70e4ebcf9ee3a6

Yet when I add it to the URL I still get an error that I needed to provide an auth_token. How does that make sense?
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/176722013/media/recent?client_id=5b5a6e95469f465f9f70e4ebcf9ee3a6

The app is in sandbox mode. When I attempt to submit it for review I must provide the purpose for the app. Upon selecting " I want to display my Instagram posts on my website." as the purpose I get the following message:

> You do not need to submit for review for this use case. If you are a
>   developer and you want to display Instagram content on your website,
>   then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client
>   in sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any sandbox
>   user that grants you permission.

I am truly at a loss for how to proceed. Thanks for any support

Answer (score 0):

As of June 1st, 2016, you need `access_token` to access API, where did u read: `either a client_id or an auth_token` ?

authenticate and get `access_token` and use to get API response.

Comment: The API response without client_id or auth_token is:

{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthParameterException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."}}

I assumed only one of the two was required

Comment: that may be a bug is error reporting in API response, in the documentation it states that `access_token` is required: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

@snucky you don't need authentication *but you do need* the users permission - from what I gather, instagram is accessible only by registered users - so you still need the *access token* - but instead of a server-explicit you need client-implicit.

Make a http request from your client to the api/authorize **with** the `?client_id=ID` AND A `redirect_uri=http://yoursite.com/` when the user allows the application, you'll receive an `access_token` in the url, which you will then use *in every subsquent instagram call*

read more [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)